# How to setup Azure Time Series Insights to receive and visualise boolean data?

Tags: azure-timeseries-insights

I'm currently sending data via EventHub to Time Series Insight with the help of following classes serialised to `JSON`:

```
public class DataItemBase
{
    public string VariableName { get; set; }
    public string SystemId { get; set; }
    public string DeviceTimestamp { get; set; }
}

public class DataItemDouble : DataItemBase
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
}

public class DataItemBool : DataItemBase
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

The data is received ok and is easily queryable when the `value` is `double`. However, I am unable to display the data when it's received as `boolean`. The value column is marked as (T/F) which seems to indicate that TSI understand the received data format correctly.
[image: Received boolean data]

The question is, how to display this boolean data on the TSI online viewer?
For a reference, this is the link to Microsofts Contonso example environment: https://insights.timeseries.azure.com/preview/samples

I suspect this is all up to assign the **instance** with a correct **type**, in the environment. I have created `DeviceData` type which is assigned to the TSI instance. This `DeviceData` type has a property named **NumericData** with `$event['value'].Double` definition. This works as expected, however I don't seem to find a similar solution for the `boolean` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only numeric data can be plotted in the TSI Explorer, so in order to display a chart with your boolean values you can create a Type variable with a [conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/reference-time-series-expression-syntax#conversion-functions) function in the Time Series Expression to cast the bool to a long or a double `toDouble($event.value.Bool)`

You might want to create a [categorical variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/concepts-variables#categorical-variables) to have True/False labeled and select custom colors

```
"Status": {
"kind": "categorical",
  "value": {
 "tsx": "toLong($event.value.Bool)"},
  "interpolation": {
    "kind": "step",
    "boundary": {
      "span" : "PT1M"
    }
  },
  "categories": [
    {
      "values": [0],
      "label": "False"
    },
    {
      "values": [1],
      "label": "True"
    }
  ],
  "defaultCategory": {
    "label": "Not Applicable"
  }
}
```

Comment: What about storing the boolean values as longs in TSI ?